# Jquery click working only once

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to draw lines between two points. I managed to do that but the problem is it only works once.The second time i click on a circle nothing's happening

> This works only in modern browsers

```js
var click = false;
var x1;
var y1;
var x2;
var y2;
$('circle').click(function () {
    if (click == false) {
        x1 = $(this).attr('cx')
        y1 = $(this).attr('cy')
        click = true;
    } else {
        click = false;
        x2 = $(this).attr('cx');
        y2 = $(this).attr('cy')
        var x=$('<line x1="' + x1 + '" y1="' + y1 + '" x2="' + x2 + '" y2="' + y2 + '" stroke-width="30" stroke="green" stroke-linecap="round"/>')
        $('svg').append(x)
       
       $("body").html($("body").html());
    }
})
```

```css
line{
    transition:.5s all;
    stroke-dasharray:2000;
    stroke-dashoffset:2000;
   -webkit-animation:move 1s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move{
    100%{
        stroke-dashoffset:0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" height="800">
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
    <circle cx="120" cy="30" r="30" />
    <circle cx="210" cy="30" r="30" />
    <circle cx="300" cy="30" r="30" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
    <circle cx="120" cy="120" r="30" />
    <circle cx="210" cy="120" r="30" />
    <circle cx="300" cy="120" r="30" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="120" r="30" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="210" r="30" />
    <circle cx="120" cy="210" r="30" />
    <circle cx="210" cy="210" r="30" />
    <circle cx="300" cy="210" r="30" />
    <circle cx="120" cy="300" r="30" />
    <circle cx="210" cy="300" r="30" />
    <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="30" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="300" r="30" />
</svg>
```

> EDIT: This seems to work in snippet but not in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/m2g6w80y/4/

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you are clicking **on** the circle and not on the line?

Comment: @DarkAshelin That is the weirdest thing ever happened it doesn't work here http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/m2g6w80y/4/

Comment: It works in the snippet because the script is part of the body and run again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Since you are replacing content using

```
$("body").html($("body").html());
```

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', 'circle', function () {
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6snv1ayu/)

Comment: Thank you this worked fine but why did it work in the snippet ?

Comment: I mean it didn't work in the fiddle but works on the snippet above

Comment: @Akshay, I have to identify that

Comment: Maybe some special feature on SO ?